# How to do simple operations on the .Net side using NETLink`?

Tags: .netlink

I am trying to learn how the `NETLink` functionality works. Consider the following example:

I import the library:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
```

I fire up the runtime environment:

```
InstallNET[];
```

I create a console so I can see things on the .Net side:

```
ShowNETConsole[]
```

I try to create an integer on the environment.

```
integer1=NETNew["System.Int32",4]
```

It fails

> NET::noctor: No public constructor exists for the .NET type
>   System.Int32.

So I just try to create an integer object first.

```
integer1=NETNew["System.Int32"]
```

I try to look what value it has by default:

```
integer1//NETObjectToExpression
```

> 0

If someone knows how to change the value of this created integer object from 0 to 4 then please help.

I try another approach:

```
integer1=MakeNETObject[4]
integer2=MakeNETObject[8]
```

I try to output the result of simple multiplication on the .Net side:

```
LoadNETType["System.Console"]
System`Console`Out@WriteLine[integer1]
System`Console`Out@WriteLine[integer2]
System`Console`Out@WriteLine[integer1*integer2]
```

It is not working. I get 4 and 8 but why am I not getting 32 on my console?

Also why can't I write to the console like this,

```
console=LoadNETType["System.Console"]
console@WriteLine["Hello world!"]
```

when I can clear the console like this:

```
consoleWindow=ShowNETConsole[]
consoleWindow@Clear[]
```

And what is the difference between the following lines:

```
System`Console`Out`WriteLine[integer1]
System`Console`Out@WriteLine[integer1]
System`Console`WriteLine[integer1]
System`Console@WriteLine[integer1]
```

What is the difference between backtick and @ sign? Why sometimes backtick and sometimes @ works?

Comment: this works : ``Needs["NETLink`"]; ShowNETConsole[]; LoadNETType["System.Console"];
Console`Out@WriteLine["Hello from .NET"] ``